# What is the best way, if at all, to implement a sorting function with internal state?

Tags: scala

What is the best way to implement a sorting function that has an internal state received else where?

Something like:

```
  type Sorter[Item] = (Item, Item) => Boolean

  type StringSorter = Sorter[String]

  def customSorter : StringSorter = (i1,i2) =>
   {
    val i1Cnt = itemCountMap.get(i1)
    val i2Cnt = itemCountMap.get(i2)
    if (i1Cnt==None || i2Cnt==None ) {
       i1<i2
    } else {
      i1Cnt.get<i2Cnt.get
    }
  }
```

And here is an example:

```
val l1 = List("a","b","c")
val itemCountMap = Map("a"->2,"b"->3,"c"1)

l1.sortWith(customSorter)
//The returned list will be ["c","a","b"]
```

I am pretty new to Scala, and in general, lambda functions are not suppose to have states (right?).

Why you ask? 'cause I am using a generic type lists in spark which later, deep in the code of the executors, I want to analyze based on a specific order, and this order may depend on some static list, and I also want to control this order function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this `i1Cnt==null` will never be true because `get` on **Map** never returns `null`, it returns an **Option** WHICH IS NOT A NULL, it is very different.

Second, there is no problem with state in a lambda, there is a problem with mutable shared state *(and not only in a lambda, but everywhere)*.

Third, your function would be better if it receives the **Map** to use instead of relying on a global variable.

Fourth, here is the fixed code.

```
type Sorter[Item] = (Item, Item) => Boolean

def customSorter(map: Map[String, Int]): Sorter[String] = { (s1, s2) =>
  (map.get(s1), map.get(s2)) match {
    case (Some(i1), Some(i2)) => i1 < i2
    case _                    => s1 < s2
  }
}
```

*You can see it running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/BreiQu2yTz2MrFfeZNRtRQ/3))*

Comment: thanks for the fixes and the reply. Since the sorter is generic and passed down to the actual sortWith usage, I am hoping to avoid passing additional parameter (map) and was hopping to pass it as part of the function... Is it possible?

Comment: @1LeveL1 not sure what you mean.

Comment: my code receives a type of a generic sorter ((T,T) -> Boolean) , which later is applied on the dataset. The actual sorter is created on the "main" level, and passed to the inner functionality. Adding a new parameter, the map, is something that is relevant only to a specific sorter, so I wouldnt want to change the api just couse now I wanted to try I new sorter with a static map in it... So I was wandering if it is possible to create a sorter with inner map value, initiated in the "creation" of the customSorter

Comment: @1LeveL1 I haven't changed your API `Sorter` is still just a function and `sortWith` just expect as a function, the one that requires a **Map** is your specific `customSorter` instantiate whenever you want and pass it down to your code. My code does exactly what you are asking it to do.

Comment: appricate the reply and comments, maybe I haven't explained myself well, but it is not quit it, cause I still need to pass the map to the place where the code is invoked. Was hopping to hide this

Comment: @1LeveL1 no you do not need to... In **Main** `val myMap = ???`, `val mySorter = customSorter(map)`, `foo(sorter = mySorter)` - In **Foo** `val data = ???`, `val result = data.sortWith(sorter)`. See, no need to know this uses a **Map** or whatever. Because on **foo** you won't call `customSorter` you will user the **Sorter** that was given to you, it will be in the main or wherever you are setting up the **Sorter** that you need to call `customSorter` using your **Map**; because `customSorter` IS NOT A SORTER is a method that takes a **Map** and returns a **Sorter**.

Comment: Ohhh, scala!! Thanks, got it!!